# Converting excel formula to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

This is Excel file where I can Use formula to get `TAT ORIG`:

[image]

```
=IF((X3-W3)*24<=24,(X3-W3)*24,
IF(AND(WEEKDAY(W3,2)<6,WEEKDAY(X3,2)<6),(NETWORKDAYS(W3,X3)-1+MOD(X3,1)-MOD(W3,1))*24,
IF(OR(WEEKDAY(W3,2)>5,WEEKDAY(X3,2)>5),(NETWORKDAYS(W3,X3)*24))))
```

this is the formula I used to get value for `TAT ORIG` in EXCEL

I need same formula to be converted 
or trick to get the same value in existing SQL table, with column name `tat_orig`

in this table I need `tat_orig` to be calculated with SQL query:

[image]

Comment: We need more context. Few people will spend the time to dissect that excel formula. Use as many words as you need. Also you didn't provide what is TAT ORIG. Just explain what the conditions are to get the end result.

Comment: I strongly suggest to try and split down the excel formula... you dont't want to end up with numerous CASE statements embedded in each other - which is basically what Excel's formula "IF(A,1,IF(B,2,IF..." will lead to.

Comment: yeah im ok with CASE WHEN statement to get desired output..

Comment: whatever i have posted...tats the only material i have .... plz help asap friends

Comment: Have you tried writing this in SQL? I don't think most people will just write your queries for you.

Comment: UPDATE   table1
SET table1.tat_orig = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(Hour, time_created, time_responded) % 24) + '.'
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(minute, time_created, time_responded) % 100)                                                                                this is what i have done to get wait time in sql... using these i want someone to build query which will calculate turn around time(tat_orig) for me. for which i have uploaded excel formula which calculate exactly what i want in Excel, but i need sql Query plz help

Comment: DATEPART replaces WEEKDAY, but your biggest problem is NETWORKDAYS, you will have to implement an auxiliary calendar table or write a stored procedure to match the formula on http://superuser.com/questions/35716/equivalent-of-excels-networkdays-function-with-jet-ado. I'll try writing it and get back to you. It would be of great help to post the data in text so that responders can copy/paste it.

Comment: thanks @thor2k and luv u bro, plz help me

Comment: This seems like a request to complete a part of OP's work, which the poster does not understand.

Answer (score 6):

Wow, I did not expect this to take so long. Here's what I've got:

```
--Network days shim
IF OBJECT_ID(N'NETWORKDAYS', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.NETWORKDAYS;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.NETWORKDAYS(@d1 datetime, @d2 datetime )
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @w1 int = DATEPART(weekday, @d1);
    DECLARE @w2 int = DATEPART(weekday, @d1);
    DECLARE @dd float = FLOOR(DATEDIFF(ms, @d1, @d2) / 86400000.0);

    -- network days is based on a holidays table; I just added this date arbitrarily so that
    -- the results match what Excel says
    DECLARE @holidays TABLE(holiday datetime);
    INSERT INTO @holidays VALUES
        ('2016-06-15');

    RETURN (@dd + @w2 - @w1) / 7 * 5 +
            @w2 - @w1 + 1 +
            IIF(@w2 = 7, -1, 0) +
            IIF(@w1 = 1, -1, 0) +
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @holidays WHERE @d1 <= holiday AND holiday < @d2);
END
GO

-- turn around time shim
IF OBJECT_ID(N'TURNAROUND', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.TURNAROUND;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TURNAROUND(@d1 datetime, @d2 datetime)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @w1 int = DATEPART(weekday, @d1);
    DECLARE @w2 int = DATEPART(weekday, @d1);
    DECLARE @nd int = dbo.NETWORKDAYS(@d1, @d2);

    DECLARE @hd float = DATEDIFF(ms, @d1, @d2) / 3600000.0;
    DECLARE @td float = DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(@d1 AS TIME), CAST(@d2 AS TIME)) / 86400000.0;

    RETURN (

    IIF(@hd <= 24.0,
        @hd,
        IIF(@w1 < 6 AND @w2 < 6,
            24 * (@nd - 1 + @td),
            IIF(@w2 > 5 OR @w1 > 5,
                24 * @nd, 0))));
END
GO

-- the data
DECLARE @items TABLE
(
 time_created datetime,
 time_responded datetime
);

INSERT INTO @items VALUES
('2016-06-10 15:42:00.000', '2016-06-15 03:03:00.000'),
('2016-06-15 01:28:00.000', '2016-06-15 03:03:00.000'),
('2016-06-14 07:46:00.000', '2016-06-15 03:03:00.000'),
('2016-07-04 05:35:25.000', '2016-07-04 19:05:48.000'),
('2016-07-04 04:56:09.000', '2016-07-04 18:29:28.000'),
('2016-07-04 09:15:33.000', '2016-07-04 22:08:43.000'),
('2016-07-04 08:44:24.000', '2016-07-04 21:40:57.000'),
('2016-07-04 07:14:51.000', '2016-07-04 21:39:24.000');

-- the results
SELECT  time_created, time_responded, dbo.TURNAROUND(time_created, time_responded) AS [TAT Orig] FROM @items;
```

The difficult part was figuring out the date arithmetic. You do not have to declare functions--they are there for clarity and calculating middle values, but technically you should be able to use the return values in a `SELECT` statement.

BTW, you're out of luck if your computed column is taking values from the *next* row--it's not impossible in SQL, but it is close.

I hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

I added the date diff big shim. I added test data one year appart.

```
--Big datediff shim
IF OBJECT_ID(N'DATEDIFFBIG', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.DATEDIFFBIG;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION DATEDIFFBIG(@d1 datetime, @d2 datetime)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT(bigint, DATEDIFF(day, @d1, @d2)) * 86400000 -
        DATEDIFF(second, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @d1), 0), @d1) * 1000 +
        DATEDIFF(second, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @d2), 0), @d2) * 1000;
END
GO

--Network days shim
IF OBJECT_ID(N'NETWORKDAYS', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.NETWORKDAYS;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.NETWORKDAYS(@d1 datetime, @d2 datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @w1 int = DATEPART(weekday, @d1);
    DECLARE @w2 int = DATEPART(weekday, @d1);
    DECLARE @dd float = FLOOR(dbo.DATEDIFFBIG(@d1, @d2) / 86400000.0);

    -- network days is based on a holidays table; I just added this date arbitrarily so that
    -- the results match what Excel says
    DECLARE @holidays TABLE(holiday datetime);
    INSERT INTO @holidays VALUES
        ('2016-06-15');

    RETURN (@dd + @w2 - @w1) / 7 * 5 +
            @w2 - @w1 + 1 +
            IIF(@w2 = 7, -1, 0) +
            IIF(@w1 = 1, -1, 0) +
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @holidays WHERE @d1 <= holiday AND holiday < @d2);
END
GO

-- turn around time shim
IF OBJECT_ID(N'TURNAROUND', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.TURNAROUND;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TURNAROUND(@d1 datetime, @d2 datetime)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @w1 int = DATEPART(weekday, @d1);
    DECLARE @w2 int = DATEPART(weekday, @d1);
    DECLARE @nd int = dbo.NETWORKDAYS(@d1, @d2);

    DECLARE @hd float = dbo.DATEDIFFBIG(@d1, @d2) / 3600000.0;
    DECLARE @td float = dbo.DATEDIFFBIG(CAST(@d1 AS TIME), CAST(@d2 AS TIME)) / 86400000.0;

    RETURN (

    IIF(@hd <= 24.0,
        @hd,
        IIF(@w1 < 6 AND @w2 < 6,
            24 * (@nd - 1 + @td),
            IIF(@w2 > 5 OR @w1 > 5,
                24 * @nd, 0))));
END
GO

-- the data
DECLARE @items TABLE
(
 time_created datetime,
 time_responded datetime
);

INSERT INTO @items VALUES
('2016-06-10 15:42:00.000', '2016-06-15 03:03:00.000'),
('2016-06-15 01:28:00.000', '2016-06-15 03:03:00.000'),
('2016-06-14 07:46:00.000', '2016-06-15 03:03:00.000'),
('2016-07-04 05:35:25.000', '2016-07-04 19:05:48.000'),
('2016-07-04 04:56:09.000', '2016-07-04 18:29:28.000'),
('2016-07-04 09:15:33.000', '2016-07-04 22:08:43.000'),
('2016-07-04 08:44:24.000', '2016-07-04 21:40:57.000'),
('2016-07-04 07:14:51.000', '2016-07-04 21:39:24.000'),
('2015-07-04 07:14:51.000', '2016-07-04 21:39:24.000');

-- the results
SELECT  time_created, time_responded, dbo.TURNAROUND(time_created, time_responded) AS [TAT Orig] FROM @items;
```

Comment: wooooh .....hats off to you bro...you are truly genius and born Legend...this is wat i need...and u did it like a charm...this is exactly i want, now do me a small favor how can i implement this code in my existing table with values already exist in my column time_Created, time_responded , this is what i m trying now ....alter table dbo.FinalExtract
add tat_orig float

update dbo.FinalExtract
set tat_orig =

Comment: i tried this ....
update dbo.FinalExtract
set tat_orig =  dbo.TURNAROUND(time_created,time_responded) from dbo.FinalExtract
but i m getting error : Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Thanks. You can define computed columns in T-SQL with an equation, e.g. , [Name] = [First] + ' ' + [Last]; of course in your case the computation is way more complex, but it doesn't mean it cannot be inlined. About the overflow, try lowering the date diff specifiers from milliseconds (ms) to seconds--I just happen to default to the highest precision available.

Comment: its not happening ...the desire output value gets changed....if i changed to seconds...all i want only 2 places after decimal point eg. 1.58 or 19.28

Comment: Hmm, there is a cap in the millisecond date difference between start and end date (24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds, because the function return type is int), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx.

You'll need to use DATEDIFF_BIG (SQL Server 2016) or a custom date diff parser otherwise, check out the accepted answer at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/58e74e27-e676-4d8d-a36a-0725ba7b8389/datediff-function-resulted-in-an-overflow?forum=transactsql. Seconds should not overflow--the cap is 68 years.

Comment: Please provide the failing data--in text format--so that I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Never mind, I edited the answer with the big date diff shim.

Comment: yippi... it worked for me @thor2k...but i need ur help for next columns in excel :( will u able to do this ? i have this task to be completed by today... as tommorow i have to submit everything .. it will cost me my job.. plz help if u can reach me gr8raj at gmail dot com..

Comment: formulas in excel for WEWE :=IF(Y3=0,IF(NETWORKDAYS(W3,X3)=0,0,NETWORKDAYS(W3,X3)+MOD(X3,1)-MOD(W3,1))*24,IF(NETWORKDAYS(Y3,X3)=0,0,NETWORKDAYS(Y3,X3)+MOD(X3,1)-MOD(Y3,1))*24) ........................cell Y3 include nothing

Comment: I gave you the NETWORKDAYS function; whenever you see MOD([date], 1) in Excel you are stripping the date part; replace MOD([d2], 1)-MOD([d1], 1) with dbo.DATEDIFFBIG(CAST(@d1 AS TIME), CAST(@d2 AS TIME)) / 86400000.0. Finally, replace blank 'Y' with 0 with an UPDATE statement. Good luck!

Comment: i tried to do that in many ways.. it just a small and last request can u write the query for me in comment section... @thor2k...i will be very much thankfull to u

Comment: Bro plz be back i need ur help

Comment: Still not able to resolve ...rest of my queries, @thor2k u know what i exactly want.. can u plz come online to help me